# passing API data from page 1 to another dart page on flutter

Tags: database, api, flutter, dart, mobile

page that already has data from the API, then I want to send the API data to the next page.

example: when we click the food list, a description of the food that is clicked will appear or when we click the data on another page, it is more detailed than the data on the list

The following is the code from the start page :

```js
var notifikasiSiswa = [];

//====================== Fungsi ListView ================================
class _NotifikasiSiswaState extends State<NotifikasiSiswa> {
  
  Future<SharedPreferences> _sprefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  int id;


  @override
  Future<Null> getData() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await _sprefs;
    int data = prefs.getInt('id');

    this.setState(() {
      id = data ;
    });
    // counter = data;

    // api coba dsni
    NotifikasiSiswaMo.getPengumuman(id.toString()).then((value) {
      notifikasiSiswa = value;
      this.setState(() {
        notifikasiSiswa = value;
      });

      print("muncul");
    });

    // print(token);
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      getData();
    });

  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Materi Siswa"),),
        body: ListView.builder(   // Auto Scroll Jika Data yang dimunculkan banyak
          reverse: true,
          itemCount: notifikasiSiswa.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index){
            return Center(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 15.0 ),
                  child: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                          height: 100,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(_borderRadius),
                            gradient: LinearGradient(
                                colors: [Colors.white, Colors.white],
                                begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                                end: Alignment.bottomRight),
                          )
                      ),
                      Positioned.fill(child: InkWell(
                        splashColor: Colors.blue.withAlpha(30),
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                            return NotifikasiSiswaDetail(
                              s_date : notifikasiSiswa[index].date,
                              s_title : notifikasiSiswa[index].title,
                              s_message :notifikasiSiswa[index].message
                            );
                            },
                          ));
                        },
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                                child:
                             Center(
                                 child: Icon(Icons.notifications_active))
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                                flex: 4,
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, //Vertical dengan posisi aligmn start
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text(notifikasiSiswa[index].date ?? "00/00/00",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.black45,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 6.0,
                                    ),
```

how on the next page ?

Answer (score 1):

final List args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;Provided that I understood your question correctly, you can pass data to a new page using the `arguments` parameter in your `Navigator.pushNamed()`.

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/newPage', arguments: /* data you want to pass */);
```

To access this data from the new page you can use this line inside its `build` method.

```
final args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
```

You can learn more about this here: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments

Answer (score 1):

You have (at least) two options here:

1. **Save the data in the state**. If the data is not so big and complex, you can carry it around via state.
2. **Make a new request**. If you need a lot more details than just title and description such as comments, like, shares, etc. then you better make a new request. Yes, it costs you more in terms of bandwidth and also money, but it gives you more room to work with.